# multi-index dataframe to dict of row lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe of mixed type data with a few million rows, each row has 50 columns.  During my pre-processing of my dataset, I want to access particular rows based on a multi-index built from 4 columns.  The columns for the multi-index are a mix of string and datetime.  I want to access the rows millions of times, sometimes to read the vals, sometimes to edit some of the values on that row, so it needs to be fast.  I do not want to pre-process this in a database right now, I just want to store and read the data from csv and process it on my local machine, then do some analysis with pandas.

I have tried setting a multi-index and using

```
df.loc[(multi-index),:]
```

but it is slow to retrieve the row data.  So, to make it faster, I converted the df to dict with the multi-index as the key and the row as a list for the value.  Lookups and edits are good for me now and the time cost for going from dataframe => dict => dataframe is small, however, I am wondering if I can make it quicker.

The question is:
The built-in

```
pd.DataFrame.to_dict(df,orient='index')
```

almost gets the data into what I want, but it seems to be slow as it puts the data into a dict of row dicts(each row of data is itself a dict with teh key being the column name), I want a dict of row lists (just a list of the values of each row).  Is there not a way to do this apart from just doing my own, which is still quite fast anyway:
ie.

```
cols = list(df_test.columns)    
for row in df_test.itertuples():    
    dict_test[(row[16],row[18],row[6],row[10])] = list(row[1:])
```

Note: to go back the other way, I can just use:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_test,orient='index')
df_test.columns = cols
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Updating rows with .loc even into a MultiIndex should be fast. It might be slow if for some reason it's changing the dtype or making a copy BUT if you are careful this won't be the case (and it will be fast). OR if you are using `.apply` rather than vectorized methods. Can you share how you are doing this in pandas code?